# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Tengo este error

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
>   reference: element is not attached to the page document

ya busque soluciones pero ninguna me ayuda a resolver mi problema o almenos que yo la este implementando de manera erronea agradeceria su ayuda.

aqui es donde ocurre el error exactamente en suc.selectByIndex(i); segun me indica el stacktrace

```
    public void Descargar()
{

        jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0,300)");

        WebElement sucursal_dropdown;
        try {

            sucursal_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHContenidoPag_ddlRPU"));
            sucursal_dropdown.click();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            sucursal_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHContenidoPag_ddlRPU"));
            sucursal_dropdown.click();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Select suc = new Select(sucursal_dropdown);

        List<WebElement> list = suc.getOptions();

        int total_list = list.size();

        System.out.println("List number is "+total_list);


        for(int i =0; i<total_list;i++)
        {


        jse.executeScript("scroll(0,300)");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        sucursal_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHContenidoPag_ddlRPU"));

        suc.selectByIndex(i);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        jse.executeScript("scroll(0,1300)");

        for(int o =2;o<3;o++)
        {

            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHMenuIzq_GVHistorial_ctl0"+o+"_DescargaPDF")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            /*driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHMenuIzq_GVHistorial_ctl0"+i+"_DescargaXML")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/

        }

        for(int p =10;p<26;p++)
        {

            driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHMenuIzq_GVHistorial_ctl"+p+"_DescargaPDF")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            /*driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHMenuIzq_GVHistorial_ctl"+i+"_DescargaXML")).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/

        }

    }


}
```

de antemano agradesco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez necesites actualizar la variable `suc` justo antes de usarla con la variable `sucursal_dropdown`. Cuando inicializas la variable `suc` la inicializas, pero desues cuando la vas a usar no la actualizas de nuevo con el valor de sucursal_dropdown:

```
sucursal_dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_PHContenidoPag_ddlRPU"));
// Aqui yo actualizaria el select que quieres usar
suc = new Select(sucursal_dropdown);
suc.selectByIndex(i);
```

Comment: Si de echo eso hice solo que se me olvidó actualizar la pregunta ya con la respuesta solo tenía que llamar la variable cuando la fuera a usar. Así que cree suc1 = new Select(sucursal_dropdown);